# Number showing as NaN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-spring

I'm using react-spring to make a component which counts from zero (0) to ten (10) over a 10 second duration:

```
export default function Counter() {
    const props = useSpring({
        from: { number: 0 },
        to: { number: 10 },
        config: {
            duration: 10000
        } 
    });

    return (
        <animated.h1>
           {props.number}
        </animated.h1>
    )
}
```

This results in a large floating point number that counts upward when it renders. I now just want to just show the integer value instead of the floating point.

Using:

```
<animated.h1>
   {props.number.toFixed()}
</animated.h1>
```

Yields: `TypeError: props.number.toFixed is not a function`

Using:

```
<animated.h1>
   {Number(props.number).toFixed()}
</animated.h1>
```

Renders 'NaN' where the Counter component is.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `props.number` is a number but it's not, it's an instance of `AnimatedValue` from `react-spring` so you can't apply your typical functions to it and what not.

I'm pretty sure if you wanna format that number value you can just do something like `{props.number.interpolate(number => number.toFixed())}`

Comment: This makes it look like the 'innerText' example on react-spring's website is incorrect then: https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/basics

Comment: I guess the difference is that yours has a longer duration than the example? If you paste their code in exactly does it only ever show the a decimal number up to 2 places?